# MFC radio buttons - DDX_Radio and DDX_Control behavior

Tags: c++, mfc, radio-button

I have an MFC dialog in which there are two radio buttons. I have put them in a nice group, their IDCs are one after each other (`RB_LEFT, RB_RIGHT`).

I want to use `DDX_Radio` so I can access the buttons using an integer value so in the function `DoDataExchange` I call :

```
DDX_Radio(pDX, RB_LEFT, mRBLeftRight);
```

where `mRBLeftRight` is a member variable of `integer` type. I also need to edit the buttons properties so I wanted to use a `DDX_Control` to map them on member variables `mRBLeft` and `mRBRight` (`CButton`):

```
DDX_Control(pDX, RB_LEFT, mRBLeft);
DDX_Control(pDX, RB_RIGHT, mRBRight);
```

Now if I do the call to `DDX_Control`, whenever `DoDataExchange` is called, the application crashes because `DDX_Control` forces `RB_LEFT` to handle a message that `DDX_Radio` cannot handle. This part I understand.

I decided to not use `DDX_Control` (removed the calls in `DoDataExchange`) and just keep a pointer to my radio buttons (`CButton*`) in my classes. So in my `OnInitDialog` function, I do the following calls :

```
mRBLeft= ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(RB_LEFT));
mRBRight = ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(RB_RIGHT));
```

Now as long as I don't use `mRBLeft` it's going to be fine, but if I do, bam, crash on `DoDataExchange`. The thing that really puzzles me is if I change my left radio button using
`((CButton*)GetDlgItem(RB_LEFT)->SetCheck(true)`
it's going to work. Sooo what's the difference ?

(I know it's a lot of hassle for little, but I just wanna understand the mechanics)

Comment: I read somewhere that I shouldn't store a pointer returned from GetDlgItem, which is probably right, perhaps this is the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TBH Its even easier than JC's post leads you to believe.

```
DDX_Control( pDX, IDC_RADIO3, m_r3 );
DDX_Control( pDX, IDC_RADIO4, m_r4 );

m_Val   = 0;
DDX_Radio( pDX, IDC_RADIO3, m_Val );
```

You need to mark the FIRST radio button in the group with `WS_GROUP` (In this case `IDC_RADIO3`). You are now good to go and it will automatically select `IDC_RADIO3`).

Now to keep `m_Val` up to date it is probably worth putting a click handler on all the radio buttons in the group.  Inside that function, simply, call `UpdateData( TRUE );`  `m_Val` will now point to the index of the radio button in the group.

Comment: I did exactly this.. trust me it will crash if you use the m_r3.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here : http://www.flounder.com/getdlgitem.htm

There IS a problem with using `DDX_Control` and `DDX_Radio` at the same time :) This is a small hack to get around the problem.

> **Radio button variables**
>
> Another intrinsic problem, which
>   represents some sort of strange
>   philosophical viewpoint of Microsoft,
>   is that you must not be allowed to
>   create control variables for radio
>   buttons. This makes no sense. They
>   have some weird idea that the only way
>   you will ever manipulate radio buttons
>   is via an index. This is hopelessly
>   inadequate. Therefore, you have to go
>   through some serious contortions to
>   get control variables for your radio
>   buttons.
>
> The first thing you have to do is go
>   back and mark all radio buttons as
>   having the `WS_GROUP` style. Only
>   radio buttons with a `WS_GROUP` style
>   can have a control variable. However,
>   if you mark all of them with
>   `WS_GROUP`, create the control
>   variables, and then remove the
>   `WS_GROUP` attribute, everything works
>   just fine, thank you. Why we have to
>   go through these extra steps makes no
>   sense whatsoever, but like the derived
>   classes problem, I've been complaining
>   about this for years with no effect.
>   My problem is that I keep forgetting
>   to go back and undo all the `WS_GROUP`
>   attributes, so the first time I run
>   the program after this I find that all
>   my radio buttons are one-button
>   groups. Whoops. $#%! Fix, and
>   recompile/relink.

Comment: Hmm I still don't get it, this has always worked as expected for me. As mentioned below, you need to set the first control's style to WS_GROUP and then it just works. Ah well, at least you have your problem solved.

Comment: FYI, I have just stumbled upon this question and thought I'd let you know, I don't have this problem, and the standard advice from Goz is what I use. It might indicate a deeper problem for you.

Comment: @Mark, by a strange coincidence I ran across this today too. This answer is bad advice, it represents a misunderstanding of the workings of DDX_Radio. You open yourself to a lot of grief when you go contrary to what Microsoft expects. There was another underlying problem in the code that was never diagnosed, and with a workaround in place it never will be.

Comment: You guys are probably right. I don't have time to investigate this issue, but I marked goz's answer as the right answer.

Comment: FWIW, the whole quote from Mr. Newcomer only relates to *the MFC class wizard* that, in the version he used back then, apparently only allowed to create a CButton member control for radio buttons marked with WS_GROUP. The whole quote doesn't make sense if not read that way.